# How do I install open office on a linux eeePC?

Tags: software-installation

I have tried to install openoffice 4.0.1 onto my eee pc, which is running linux I have tried the unpack way but apparently I do not have permission. How do I get this permission?
I have also tried the commands that I found online yet when I run the code it states there is no such file or directory, yet the file I wish to install is in the directory I am running the file from.

I am new to Linux so I apologize if I have not got the terminology correct.

Comment: LibreOffice should be installed by default on Ubuntu. Isn't it? Reading your question, I'm wondering: are you sure you are using using Ubuntu? What does `lsb_release -i` says?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com is the alternative site for non-buntu Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you use Ubuntu, I suppose that Libreoffice is already installed. I would suggest you to use it, as it is a fork of OpenOffice, and it works very well.

If yoou really need to install OpenOffice, I would not suggest you to keep Libreoffice. To remove Libreoffice:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Once Libreoffice is totally removed, go to this website (you will be sure to get the last version):

http://www.openoffice.org/download/

Or you may try this (I am not sure of the version):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/office 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openoffice
```

Answer (score -3):

**Try Kignsoft office or Libre office.**

**For Kingsoft office:**

32 bit:

```
cd && wget -O kingsoft-office-NoobsLab.deb http://goo.gl/sln1Sb

sudo dpkg -i kingsoft-office-NoobsLab.deb

rm kingsoft-office-NoobsLab.deb
```

64 bit:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

cd && wget -O kingsoft-office-NoobsLab.deb http://goo.gl/sln1Sb

sudo dpkg -i kingsoft-office-NoobsLab.deb

rm kingsoft-office-NoobsLab.deb*
```

**To get Libre office:**

http://www.libreoffice.org/download

Comment: You don't really answer how to install Open Office in your answer. Do you? You should at least explain why you are suggesting this alternative. Also I don't like the link to libreoffice. Why do you suggest to install it with a download instead of installing it with the software-center or with apt-get?

Comment: I told that al the things because he has mentioned that he is new to linux. So I suppose it's better to say that. Why you do not like that?

Comment: Why do you give him a link to a Ubuntu-One download? Why not a proper link from a official website?